# Something wrong with spaces in zenity trying in a script

Tags: shell-script, quoting, zenity

While this is directly executed in terminal it works fine

```
zenity --info --text "pure info" --title "get info"
```

But this script doen't work what's wrong?

```
!/bin/bash
ZEN="--info --text \"pure info\" --title \"get info\""
zenity $ZEN
```

The script outputs like : "info in text and '"jeevan in title. It is skipping the remaining part.
Is it because the space (special character) loses it's special meaning inside double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the command `zenity` sees multiple arguments in the first case, and only one (including a lot of spaces) in the second.

With the following `awk` program, you can quickly output what the shell expands the arguments to. As it happens, `zsh` I could reproduce your problem:

```
% awk 'BEGIN {for (i in ARGV) print "ARGV["i"] =", ARGV[i]}' $ZEN                                               
ARGV[0] = awk
ARGV[1] = --info --text "pure info" --title "get info"
```

Whereas in `bash` it looks almost like it should look (notice that the quoted strings are split in words):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for (i in ARGV) print "ARGV["i"] =", ARGV[i]}' $ZEN
ARGV[0] = awk
ARGV[1] = --info
ARGV[2] = --text
ARGV[3] = "pure
ARGV[4] = info"
ARGV[5] = --title
ARGV[6] = "get
ARGV[7] = info"
```

There should be a shell word splitting option responsible for this behavior.

This, however, worked:

```
set -- --info --text "pure info" --title "get info"
zenity "$@"
```

*Edit:*

Shells are a bit stupid with word splitting by default, see the behavorior in my `bash` example above: `"pure` and `info"` are two separate words. As this is annoying in parsing of command line options, some special functionality has been created in the treatment of `"$@`. Quoting the `bash` manual, section Special Parameters:

> ```
>    @      Expands  to  the positional parameters, starting from one.  When
>           the  expansion  occurs  within  double  quotes,  each  parameter
>           expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1"
>           "$2" ...
> ```

I have not found a way to get the special treatment of `$@` into normal variable expansion, but there could be a trick.

The `set` command sets the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, .... As such, the "Give me all"-version of positional parameters, `$@`, is available as well.

Comment: Glad it works! Please post another Q for another question. You might want to focus your question on what does not work exactly.

Comment: but bro can u tell me what made the difference?? please

Comment: Since bash has arrays (named arrays, I mean), you can use them to get the same array behavior: `ZEN=(--info --text "pure info" --title "get info"); zenity "${ZEN[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is to `eval`uate the whole expression so that the quotes inside the string are parsed:

```
eval zenity "$ZEN"
```

By the way, you may also use single quotes in variable definition instead of escaping double quotes:

```
ZEN='--info --text "pure info" --title "get info"'
```

And BTW2, you have missing `#` in front of `!/bin/bash`.

If you are using zsh then an alternative method is to split the parameter into words using shell parsing (taking into account quoting) with `z` flag, i.e.:

```
zenity "${(z)ZEN}"
```

Comment: If you have arrays, which both bash and zsh do, that's a simpler way of solving this. `ZEN=(--info --text "pure info" --title "get info"); zenity "${ZEN[@]}"` Using single quotes in the variable definition would not work.

Comment: @Gilles what would not work with single quotes?

Comment: `zenity $ZEN` still would pass the arguments `--info`, `--text`, `"pure`, `info"`, … just like what the asker tried. Oh, or did you mean this in combination with `eval`? That isn't clear. You should remove the bit about zsh, it's just confusing here.

Comment: I meant that he can use single quotes instead of escaping nested double-quotes - and this is only mentioned as a digression.